# how to get images from ApiControler

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, asp.net-web-api

I have created a model and a view and displayed some needed data from the model using simple GameController.

Now i am searching(didn't found anything usefull) on how to get 9 images and show them in the page using ApiController(9 images that can be used for a puzzle) and modifying the page that GameController has returned, without loading the whole page.

The idea is that i want to call the method from ApiController 9 times and to show the images in a grid/table or somewhere.

I can use an example on how to do this since i didn't found something relevant on google and someone with knowledge can do it very fast.

If something is unclear, just ask.

Thanks,
Gabriel Sas

Answer (score 1):

There is an example [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1822496.aspx/1):

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetImage()
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
    response.Content = new StreamContent(new FileStream(@"path to image")); // this file stream will be closed by lower layers of web api for you once the response is completed.
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/png");

    return response;
}
```

Comment: i tried this and it works only showing the image if i access the URL. but what is the javascript code + a button when pressed to show the image?

Comment: @Sas Gabriel You are going to need to be more specific that what javascript do I need.  It is your app, how do you want to show the images?  Are they img tags, css backgrounds, etc?  What have you tried so far that hasn't worked?  We can't write your application for you.